# "Minus x" vs "Negative x" Confusion:

Tags: linear-algebra

My teacher says that the following equation:
$$-9-1(9x-6) = 3(4x+6)$$
Should be simplified at the first stage to:
$$-9-9x+6 = 12x+18$$
He says that on the left side of the equation, we should multiply $-1$ by $9$ and $-6$ respectively, but to me this reads slightly different.

I interpret this as "negative $9$ minus $1$ times $9$ minus $1$ times $6$" which would simplify to:
$$-9-9x-6$$
The difference being that in my simplification, $6$ is subtracted from $-9-9x$ whereas in his simplification, $6$ is added to $-9-9x$.

I assume that he is right (he is the teacher after all) but I don't quite understand why I am wrong. I think this all comes down to the "minus $6$" vs. "negative $6$" issue. If you read the left side of the initial equation:
$$-9-1(9x-6)$$
If the '$-1$' part is to be read as "negative $1$" rather than "minus $1$" then what is the operation in between '$-9$' and '$-1$'. Is it a multiplication?

I often get confused by minus vs negative, does anyone have any tips or tricks for understanding this situation a bit better.

Comment: It is $(-a)\cdot (-b)=(-1)\cdot (-1)\cdot a\cdot b=1\cdot a\cdot b$

Comment: And it is $a-(-b)=a+b$ as well.

Comment: The $-1$ distributes through the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to stack exchange.

The difference between minus and negative can be a bit subtle. It basically comes down to the following: $x-y=x+(-y)$. On the lefthand side we are considering "$x$ minus $y$", on the righthand side we are considering "$x$ plus negative $y$". Technically, the "minus" notation on the left side is just shorthand for the "plus negative" notation on the right side. In your example we are therefore looking at
$$-9-1(9x-6)=-9+(-1)(9x+(-6))=-9+(-1)\cdot 9x+(-1)(-6)=-9x-3.$$
If you want you can fill in some values of $x=1,2,3,-1,-2,-3$, work out the brackets like normal and you will see that the end results should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

In your way it must be:
$$-9-1(9x-6)=-9-[1(9x-6)]=-9-[9x-6]=-9-9x+6$$
because you want to multiply first, then subtract (minus).

Answer (score 0):

Will it convince you to try with some actual numbers?

If, for example, we set $x=2$, then we have
$$ -9 -1(9x-6) = -9 -1(9\cdot 2 - 6)$$
The value inside the parenthesis is $9\cdot 2-6 = 18-6 = 12$, so the value of the whole expression is
$$ -9 - 1\cdot 12 = -9 - 12 = -21 $$

With your expression, you get
$$ -9 -9x - 6 = -9 - 18 - 6 = -33 $$
Since $-33$ is not the same as $-21$, your rewriting has not preserved the value of the expression when $x=2$. (In fact it doesn't preserve the value of the expression for *any* $x$).

---

Intuitively, if you subtract $6$ *less* than the $9x$, then you should end up with a *larger* number than you subtract all of the $9x$. But your $-9-9x-6$ will yield *less* than $-9-9x$.